# Using Jade to iterate JSON

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, pug

I am trying to iterate a JSON doc using JADE.

my server(running node.js + express) is doing the following on a .get() request,

```
app.get('/search/', function(req,res){

  // Parse the query
  var dbQuery = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  var product = dbQuery.product;
  var category = dbQuery.category;
  console.log('Searching for: ' + product + ' in ' + category);

  //Mongo DB setup then query
  var result;
  var server = new mongodb.Server('23.23.129.158', 27017, {});
  new mongodb.Db('militaryListDB', server, {}).open(function(err, client){
    if(err) throw err;

    var collection = new mongodb.Collection(client, 'products');
    collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, results){
      console.log(results);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
      res.render('results', {result: JSON.stringify(results), title: 'Test'});
    });
  });
});
```

and this is what it is rendering to the client.

```
[{"_id":"50738ebbe3d87c6beaddb6f2","name":"tv","category":"tech","cost":"30"}]
```

I have read over the jade documentation for iterating an array and I thought it would be the same for JSON, but it isn't working. It is just displaying a blank space. When I try this,

```
extends layout
block content
  div#wrapper                 
    p #{results}
```

it will display the JSON doc. But when I try this,

```
extends layout
block content
  div#wrapper                 
    p #{results.name}
```

and it displays a blank space. When it should be displaying is "tv". If someone could help me understand iterating JSON docs that would be awesome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your code you are not iterating through the `results` array, do to so you should do something like this:

```
for result in results
     p #{result.name}
```

Comment: I forgot to include this in the sample code I gave. But when I took away JSON.stringify() on the server side it worked.

Comment: Thank Jesus, finally, I've been searching hours for that little piece of code and have even contemplating painting "JADE SUCKS" on the side of a building in goats blood.  If u want another checkmark, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485595/how-do-i-send-on-object-from-mongodb-to-jade.  THANK YOU.