# How do I send on object from MongoDB to jade?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, pug

I'm trying to access an object that I retrieve from MongoDB with my client-side JS.  Specifically, I want to be able to loop through and use the arrays within the object.  Here is my server-side JS which successfully finds the `results` and logs them to terminal.

```
app.get("/post/:id", function (req, res, next) {
  var id = req.param('id');
  var query = BlogPost.findById(id).populate('author');

  BlogPost.find(query, {"answers":"true", "blanks":"true", "_id":0}, function(err, results){

  console.log('Results '+results);//This prints an object like:// { answers: [ 'more', 'One', 'more' ], blanks: ['try']}

  query.exec(function (err, post) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (!post) return next(); // 404

    res.render('post/view.jade', { post: post, results: results });
  })
})
})
```

And my jade:

```
  #luck
   #{results}
```

And then my client-side JS:

```
var results = $('#luck').html();
console.log(results.answers[2]);
```

I get `undefined` with the console.log and the results are printed on the page.

Comment: Sometimes its a list of one object so you can try Object[0].attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answer @Xinzz, but this jade:

```
for result in results
     p #{result.answers}
```

ended up working for me.  From here: [Using Jade to iterate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794078/using-jade-to-iterate-json/12794400#comment30618423_12794400)

Answer (score 3):

If the results are printed on the screen but you cannot traverse the object, then it may mean a few things:

1) The object might be an array i.e. results[0].whatever instead of results.whatever

2) The object is in string form and you need to call JSON.parse(results) before you can traverse it

```
var results = JSON.parse($('#luck').html());
console.log(results.answers[2]);
```