# Json Parse in Jade

Tags: node.js, express

I want to render my json in jade.I m sending Json Data but this give error like this

```
       app.get('/showRequestAccepted',function(req,res){
      Account.getFriends(req.user,{"friends.status":Status.Accepted},function(err,sonuc)          {
         if(err) throw err
        //Json'i formatted göstermek için  null ve 4 boşluk için
        else
        console.log(sonuc);
        res.render('profil',{sonuc:JSON.stringify(sonuc)});


        });

});
```

in Jade [Using Jade to iterate JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794078/using-jade-to-iterate-json) I find this example this is not help me

```
         each jsonObj in sonuc
          li=jsonObj.username
```

I m getting this error

```
  500 TypeError: /Users/ANTEGRUP/Desktop/passport-local-master/views/profil.jade:31 29|   30| div#userlist > 31| each jsonObj in sonuc 32| li=jsonObj.username 33| 34| Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Why stringify? You don't need to stringify, do you?

Comment: Because 'sonuc' is not valid json.when I stringify  this data.its valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing JSON and javascript objects, basically your code should be this:

```
   app.get('/showRequestAccepted',function(req,res){
   Account.getFriends(req.user,{"friends.status":Status.Accepted},function(err,sonuc) {
     if(err) throw err
     //Json'i formatted göstermek için  null ve 4 boşluk için
     else
       console.log(sonuc);
     res.render('profil',{sonuc: sonuc)});
   });
```

For your example to work, `sonuc` must be array of objects with username field in them. In javascript object literal notation this would be an example: `[{ username : 'a' }]`

Now JSON, is a data interchange format. When you do JSON.stringify(sonuc), you will get a string that represents that array. You can confirm with `typeof JSON.stringify(sonuc) === 'string'` which returns true. But in this case we need an array of objects, so `Array.isArray(sonuc)` should return true if it's array.

You might have a look at this question: [Javascript object Vs JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8294088/774086)

Comment: sonuc is returnnig like this [ { _id: 537dbb21407965a10da84630,
    status: 'accepted',
    added: Thu May 22 2014 11:54:33 GMT+0300 (EEST),
    friend: 
     { _id: 537dbb21407965a10da84630,
       salt: 'f0e95c9e47178f39ef01ca03fa25ab348feb4bc667755715a2f8da7da71436ec',
       hash: '3d44d3ece69a459b4c9356820565658667f3e4690e2fec821f85fe01aa3a810ea7ffa586c7e74d9c7d16f406352f32abc3b1179ec309026b903a3b5b2611be9b55ea72d3679e67ee7e0d7945c16a58b0f6078f239',
       username: 'user4',
       email: 'user4@g.com',
       __v: 0 } },

Comment: In this you should change your code to `li=jsonObj.friend.username`

Comment: ul
    34| 
  > 35|             each jsonObj in sonuc
    36|               li=jsonObj.friend.username
    37| 
    38| 

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: http://runnable.com/me/U377w3AFeOpZC159 I want to do like this. its almost same but not work in my code

Comment: runnable giving me 404.

Comment: http://runnable.com/U38VfqK3uhYNIPSp/loops-and-condition-in-jade-for-node-js  .I m sorry try this

Comment: Worked fine for me, upgrade to the latest jade.

Comment: this example works but my code is not work :) its so interesting.I upgraded latest jade

Comment: Then the problem is not the code you have shared. Try remove stuff from your code till you get it working. Then find out which line causes that.